# Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.9.1

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I recently installed new Linux Kernel 5.9.1 following steps mentioned on website:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

Now when I try this command(after reboot):

`` sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` ``

I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.9.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.9.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.9.1'
```

uname -r shows: 5.9.1 and I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my system. I am currently stuck at this, can someone help in solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can’t install `linux-headers-5.9.1` is that the repositories don’t have such a package. Since you built the kernel yourself, it’s up to you to provide it.

The best solution on Ubuntu is to use the kernel’s package build tools:

```
make deb-pkg
```

(from the root of the kernel source tree).

This will build a kernel image package and a kernel headers package. Installing both of those will ensure that you have the new kernel and matching headers. You shouldn’t run `make install` and `make modules_install` if you take this approach; installing the packages replaces those.

Comment: I had followed the steps mentioned in the website and I did use make install and make modules_install commands there. So what should I do then? Also were should I run make deb-pkg, the directory where the linux kernel is stored?

Comment: I know what you did, my answer takes that into account. As mentioned, you should run `make deb-pkg` from the root of the kernel source tree, *i.e.* the same directory from which you ran `make install`.

Comment: Running make deb-pkg ends up giving the following error:
`dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source`
`dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -i.git -b linux-5.9.1 subprocess returned exit status 1`
`scripts/Makefile.package:73: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed`
`make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 1`
`Makefile:1523: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed`
`make: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2`

Comment: After this I again tried running:` sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` ` Then I got: `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` After I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, I get the same error as mentioned in the original post when I run `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` `

Comment: Yes, if `make deb-pkg` didn’t complete successfully then you won’t get working packages. Once this is done correctly, you shouldn’t try to install `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` using `apt`; you’ll install the package using `dpkg -i`.

Comment: What can be the possible issue with `make deb-pkg` not working?

Comment: I can’t say based on what you show above. There should be a more detailed error above the “error: unrepresentable changes” message.

Comment: These were the only others errors that happened other then I mentioned: `dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to vmlinux-gdb.py:`
`dpkg-source: error:   new version is symlink to /home/akhil/Documents/Course_work/Sys_Prac/Asgn2/linux-5.9.1/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py`
`dpkg-source: error:   old version is nonexistent`